# Counting unique pixel value of an image

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to count the number of unique pixel values and filter out those number more than a threshold and save it in a dict.

```py
# Assume an image is read as a numpy array
np.random.seed(seed=777)
s = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(100, 100, 3))
print(s)
```

This is how I count the number of unique values(1*3 array).

```
np.unique(img.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

How can I add some logic to filter out and turn it to a dict?

Comment: which kind of image? can you provide a small reproducible example? Maybe a 5x5 to 10x10 image (or a real image with the code for the import) and the matching expected output

Comment: it's in numpy array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
np.random.seed(seed=1606)
img = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(100, 100, 3))

# set upi threshold
thresh = 2

# count unique values and set up mask
vals, counts = np.unique(img.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0, return_counts=True)
mask = counts>thresh

# form a dictionary of values/counts > threshold
out = dict(zip(map(tuple, vals[mask]), counts[mask]))
```

Output:

```
{(163, 209, 247): 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter` from `collections` module instead of using `return_counts=True`:

```
from collections import Counter

thresh = 2

counts = {pix: val for pix, val in Counter(map(tuple, np.unique(img.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0))).items()
                   if val > thresh}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Corralien's answer with `Counter` is probably cleaner, although I imagine you'll want to keep the uniqueness computation in numpy to take advantage of its optimised code.

```py
values, counts = np.unique(img.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0, return_counts=True)

res = dict(
  (tuple(value), count)
    for (value, count) in zip(values, counts)
    if count < threshold  # define threshold accordingly
)
```